# Making circular BorderDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create circular animation. Following is my code,

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: color,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                  ),
                  duration: _duration,
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Text(
                  'change',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () => change(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm setting  `borderRadius = 180` and  `margin = 99` in setState when I want to animate

But still, the layout is not circular when animated. what value of border-radius should I use?

Comment: duration: Duration(seconds: 2), please use this

Comment: I did use duration...

Comment: [will this do the job for you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-rhXZLtpv0&vl=en)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI-8QHpGIP4

Comment: I followed the exact same tutorials

Comment: @Schwern woow!.. I deleted it because someone downvoted it, your query works like a charm!!!!.. thank you very much!.. Would you post it as an answer to my original question? I will accept it as answer.. Thank you once again!

Comment: @user1241241 Downvotes happen. I've posted my answer. Good luck!